# Indecomposable modules which are the sum of 2 submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible for a module M to be a sum of 2 nonzero submodules M = K + L but not the direct 
sum of any two nonzero submodules where K,L $\neq$ $0,M$

Comment: I suppose you would also want $K,L \neq M, 0.$

Comment: Yes, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly.  For example, take $M = \mathbb{Z}$, $K = 2\mathbb{Z}$, $L = 3\mathbb{Z}$.  By the structure theorem for finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, $\mathbb{Z}$ is indecomposable.  I'd guess that it's far more rare for this not to be the case -- that is, every sum of proper submodules generating $M$ is in fact a direct sum.